# Writing disproportionation half reactions

Tags: redox

> **Question**
>   Write the half equations for the following reaction:
>   $$\ce{3OCl- -> 2Cl- + ClO3-}$$

I know that $\ce{Cl}$ is reduced from an oxidation state of 1+ to 1- (in $\ce{Cl-}$) and is oxidized from an oxidation state of 1+ to 5+ (in $\ce{ ClO3-}$)

Below is as far as I have gotten:

$$\ce{3OCl- -> ClO3- + 4e}$$
$$\ce{3OCl- + 6e -> 2Cl- }$$

I am sure this isn't correct, as I can't balance it and together they do not add up to the full equation

Comment: How did you go about balancing the reactions?

Comment: @Avnish I tried to multiply each half reactions so that they both had 24 electrons.

Comment: The atoms of an element need to be balanced in the half reactions as well.

Comment: @EllaLewis Avnish is right. Also, we need to know the medium of the reaction (acidic or basic) to be able to completely balance the half reaction. Was it given in your book?

Comment: Without supplying the details of the reaction medium, this question seems unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\ce{2OCl- + 4e -> 2Cl- + 2[O] }$$
$$\ce{2[O] + OCl- -> ClO3- + 4e}$$

P.S.

$$\ce{2[O]  -> O2}$$ is likely to happen, if [O] (nascent oxygen) is not used up in some reaction. 
Here, as soon as it is released in the first reaction (reduction), it is used up in the second (oxidation).

Hope that helps.

Comment: How can you balance the reaction without knowing the medium of the reaction (acidic or basic)?

Comment: If it's not mentioned, this is the best we can do.

Comment: Yeah, but still it is a point worth noting. The answer will differ for both mediums.

Comment: Yeah, you're right!